# AJAX ejecuta siempre status === 0

Tags: jquery, ajax

estatus de un error AJAX siempre me devuelve 0, inserta correctamente en mi BD pero no muestra mensaje de éxito, muestra mensaje de error cuando status === 0, ejecuto 3 funciones AJAX en un evento click de un botón, las dos funciones que son invocadas se ejecutan correctamente, la funcion AJAX es la que envia el mensaje que hay dentro de la condicion status === 0

```js
$("#btnGuardafactura").click(function (event) {
        
        var cantidadSim = $("#txtValorTotalSim").val();
        var cantidadArticulo = $("#txtValorTotalArticulo").val();
        //alert("guardar");
        var varFactura = $("#txtfactura").val();
        var varNombre = $("#txtNombre").val();
        var varApellidop = $("#txtApellidoA").val();
        var varApellidom = $("#txtApellidoM").val();
        var varFechaCompra = $("#txtfechaCompra").val();
        var varEmailu = $("#txtEmail").val();
        var varArchivo = $("#rutaPdf").val();

        if (cantidadSim == cantidadArticulo) {

            fn_Ajax_Articulo();
            fn_Ajax_sim();

            var cargando = $("#muestraSeccion").html("<center><img  src='../Images/cargando1.gif' height='50px' width='50px'/><br/>Un momento por favor...<center>");
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'guardarFactura',
                data: {
                    "factura": varFactura,
                    "nombre": varNombre,
                    "apellidop": varApellidop,
                    "apellidom": varApellidom,
                    "fechaCompra": varFechaCompra,
                    "emailUsuario": varEmailu,
                    "archivo":varArchivo
                },
                success: function (resultado) {
                    cargando.hide();                    
                    alert(resultado);                    

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

                        alert('Not connect: Verify Network.=(');

                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

                        alert('Requested page not found [404].');

                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

                        alert('Error Interno del Servidor [500].');

                    } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

                        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

                    } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

                        alert('Time out error.');

                    } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

                        alert('Ajax request aborted.');

                    } else {

                        alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

                    }

                }
            });


        } else {
            alert("La cantidad de articulos debe ser la misma que la cantidad de SIM")
            event.preventDefault();
        }


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

error que aparece imprimiendo las variables de .error(...) con console.log
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: dale un tercer signo igual en el if:  if (cantidadSim === cantidadArticulo)

Comment: no, mas que nada el poblema esta en el "error" de la funcion ajax

Comment: Dale un F12 y mira en network si esta llegando exactamente a donde existe `guardarFactura`

Comment: que te parece si le das un `console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` después del `error: function ....` quiero ver que te arroja el valor del jqXHR...

Comment: @Alfonso Carrasco ya imprimir con console.log las variables, arriba coloco la imagen de lo aparecio

Comment: ¿Qué es `'#btnGuardafactura'`?

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar que tiene o que hace guardarFactura? Si te arroja error 500 es problema con guardarFactura por ahí algún error de sintaxis o algún warning, depende de que lenguaje utilices por que puede que por ahí tengas algo que no has visto y tu query se ejecute bien y por eso pienses que funciona correcto.

Comment: El error 500 es un problema del lado del servidor, por lo que se entiende que el problema no es tu lado (Cliente), intenta acceder a esa url desde tu navegador usando la url completa, ejem: 192.168.10.161:8080/mi_aplicacion/guardarFactura y verifica si responde

Comment: La pregunta es bastante confusa, dice lo siguiente: *`muestra mensaje de error cuando status === 0`*, cuando en realidad, el error (según la imagen mostrada) ocurre cuando `status === 500`. **El error 500 ocurre en el servidor, no en el cliente**, por lo que, sin ver el código que se ejecuta en el servidor es imposible responder a la pregunta. Ese error puede ocurrir hasta por un símbolo cualquiera de más, dejado en el código del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente estés accediendo a un dominio:puerto distinto del que lanzas el script. Es lo que se conoce como la política del mismo origen.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_del_mismo_origen

Comment: Si fuese así, no debería mostrarlo en la consola y responder con 404 en vez de 500 *Internal Server Error*?

Answer (score 0):

El error 500 se debe a que la respuesta le sale esto

> string or binary data would be truncated

Ese es un error sql cuando intentas insertar un campo que tiene una longitud superior a la columna creada por ejemplo si insertas a la columna `nombre char(5)` Esteesunnombremuylargo, pues daría este error porque la longitud excede a los caracteres de la columna